# Change text from "Complete Purchase" to 'Place Order' on a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to change the text

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Complete Purchase" class="btn btn-primary" id="js-payment-btn" data-disable-with="Complete Purchase">
```

I want to change the button's text from "Complete Purchase" to "Place Order"

Comment: Change the `value`

Comment: why are you using input for a button?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('js-payment-btn').value = 'Place Order';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value in your input field.

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Place Order" class="btn btn-primary" id="js-payment-btn" data-disable-with="Place Order">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look the code I add a "click". When you click the button it changes the value from  "Complete Purchase" to "Place Order".

```html
<html>
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Complete Purchase" class="btn btn-primary" id="js-payment-btn" data-disable-with="Complete Purchase" onClick="change()">
    
    <script>
        function change() {
            document.getElementById("js-payment-btn").value = "Place Order";
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please look the code if you can't understand you can ask me. If my answer satisfied you then please mark it as the correct answer and vote me.

Comment: Hey Ratkim, I tried this already however, it is creating a whole new button at  the bottom of the page: https://i.gyazo.com/eeae14e6a2e41ee07c51d9c4d2994a1d.png

Comment: I think there is something wrong in your code. Can you give me the code or the link of the web page? It is not good to give an image or screenshot of a web page to check the code.